# User variables in Visual Studio .NET Solution

Tags: visual-studio, solution

When adding Build Events to a project in a .NET solution in Visual Studio (any version), you can use solution variables such as `$(SolutionDir)` or `$(PlatformName)`.

Is it possible, in any way, to add custom variables to these? Preferably to user scope (so that check-ins won't share them with team)?

I found [references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) on how to edit them on C++ solutions, but it doesn't applies to .NET solutions (by the way, the are called macros).

[image: Post Build Event with Macros Open]

Comment: What's the end goal here? There may be another way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own variables in msbuild file (read: your proj file)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx

> "Project files in Visual Studio (.csproj,.vbproj, vcxproj, and others)
>   contain MSBuild XML code that runs when you build a project by using
>   the IDE. Projects typically import one or more .targets files to
>   define their build process. For more information, see MSBuild .Targets
>   Files."

Also: Common MSBuild Project Properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx

With these concepts you can achieve whatever you want.

Comment: This doesn't really satisfy the requirement to keep them out of source control